# Most efficient way to check a URL

Tags: php, database, forms, verification

I'm trying to check if a user submitted URL is valid, it goes directly to the database when the user hits submit.
So far, I have:

```
$string = $_POST[url];
if (strpos($string, 'www.') && (strpos($string, '/')))
{
    echo 'Good';
}
```

The submitted page should be a page in a directory, not the main site, so `http://www.address.com/page` 
How can I have it check for the second `/` without it thinking it's from `http://` and that doesn't include `.com`?

Sample input:

```
 Valid:
     http://www.facebook.com/pageName
     http://www.facebook.com/pageName/page.html
     http://www.facebook.com/pageName/page.*

Invalid:
     http://www.facebook.com
     facebook.com/pageName
     facebook.com
```

Comment: Is it the same domain each time?

Comment: Post some samples of inputs that are valid and those that are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!parse_url('http://www.address.com/page', PHP_URL_PATH)) {
    echo 'no path found';
}
```

See [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) reference.

Answer (score 1):

See the [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function. This will give you the "/page" part of the URL in a separate string, which you can then analyze as desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED)
```

More information here :

http://ca.php.net/filter_var

Answer (score 0):

Maybe strrpos will help you.  It will locate the last occurrence of a string within a string

Answer (score 0):

To check the format of the URL you could use a regular expression:

preg_match [ http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php ] is a good start, but a knowledge of regular expressions is needed to make it work.

Additionally, if you actually want to check that it's a valid URL, you could check the URL value to see if it actually resolves to a web page:

```
function check_404($url) {
    $return = @get_headers($url);

    if (strpos($return[0], ' 404 ') === false)
        return true;
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would definetly recommend **against** requesting the URL unless that's a hard requirement. The performance overhead is more than significant.

Comment: Indeed, it was a secondary thought. Mostly if the case is that it's just on an infrequent update and the importance of the URL being valid is high.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regular expression to see that the URL has the correct structure. Here's [more reading on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url). You need to learn how **[PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php)** works.

A simple example for what you want (disclaimer: not tested, incomplete).

```
function isValidUrl($url) {
    return preg_match('#http://[^/]+/.+#', $url));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From here: http://www.blog.highub.com/regular-expression/php-regex-regular-expression/php-regex-validating-a-url/

```
    <?php
/**
* Validate URL
* Allows for port, path and query string validations
* @param    string      $url       string containing url user input
* @return   boolean     Returns TRUE/FALSE
*/
function validateURL($url)
{
$pattern = '/^(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&amp;?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/';
return preg_match($pattern, $url);
}

$result = validateURL('http://www.google.com');
print $result;
?>
```